# Notification sound if the application is ignored

Tags: android

I was wondering if it would be possible/how to go about having an application alert the user of a reminder in a notification sound (like receiving a text message, basically) and if the user ignores the sound, it goes off again in 5 minutes.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer and kill it when 5 minutes passed.